# Camera slows down zooming into an object while in viewport

Tags: modeling, camera

I have been encountering an issue where the camera zoom slows down then completely stops moving before I reach an object which I'm trying to zoom into.
I'm not too sure how to fix the issue and I've searched the web but still struggling to fix the problem.
Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The camera has a limited amount it can "zoom", and it doesn't move when you zoom it. There are a number of ways you can navigate despite this. The easiest is probably to "snap" the camera to the selected object by pressing the decimal (.) button on your Numpad. If you need even finer control, you can enter walk mode by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> (same key as <kbd>~</kbd>). You can then navigate with the WASD keys. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to return to normal navigation.